# Do asynchronous plausibility checks cause race conditions to arise?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, race-condition

I have a .Net 5 Web API project using EF Core and thought about data consistency for my business handlers. I personally think this question is not technology related and applies to other web frameworks as well. The following is just an example (the design might be bad)

Imagine the API provides two endpoints

- `POST /users/{userId}/documents/{documentId}` to link a user to a document
- `DELETE /users/{userId}` to delete a user

The database holds a cross table

| User | Document |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Document1 |
| User1 | Document2 |
| User2 | Document2 |

The logic to link a user to a document might look like

```
var user = await FetchUserFromDb(userId);

if(user == null) 
{
    return new NotFoundResponse($"user {userId} not found");
}

var document = await FetchDocumentFromDb(documentId);

if(document == null) 
{
    return new NotFoundResponse($"document {documentId} not found");
}

var insertResult = await InsertIntoCrossTable(userId, documentId);

return new CreatedResponse(insertResult);
```

The logic to delete a user might look like

```
var affectedRows = await DeleteUserFromDb(userId);

if(affectedRows == 0) 
{
    return new NotFoundResponse($"user {userId} not found");
}

return new NoContentResponse("user deleted successfully");
```

Currently, I don't know what happens if both requests come in at the same time. The POST request would successfully return the user and then try to retrieve the document from the database. If the user is deleted at this point, the business logic in the POST request will no longer be aware of this. The insert query statement would throw a database exception because the foreign key for the user no longer exists.

Am I wrong here and the requests are processed one after the other? Or do I as a developer have to deal with this issue specifically (by adding additional try/catch statements for database exceptions)?

Comment: Transactions can be used on operations containing selects too, if you're bothered about this

Comment: `Am I wrong here and the requests are processed one after the other?` They are not run one after the other.

Comment: @CaiusJard 1. so should I make every handler transactional? 2. what if my data source is not a database?

Comment: @mjwills so if they run simultaneously, how would you take care for it?

Comment: `so if they run simultaneously, how would you take care for it?` See the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

> Or do I as a developer have to deal with this issue specifically (by adding additional try/catch statements for database exceptions)?

You do have to deal with it some way. Either:

1. Extend your transaction to include both the select and the insert, or
2. Handle the exception (either with retries that will also retry the select or returning an error code), or
3. Don't handle the exception and let the user/UI refresh on error.

> what if my data source is not a database?

That's an impossibly broad question. So the answer is also broad: "use whatever concurrency techniques are recommended for your data source."